# How to draw a partial arc at the beggining of a LazyColumn Item Row in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My current android application contains a LazyColumn where each list item requires a coloured partial arc drawing at the beggining of the item row.

as shown here

[image]

I am concerned that i do not want to waste resources by drawing a full circle and translating the majority of it off the screen to the left i wish to only draw the visible shapes shown below.

i have followed the questions on SO that are similar to this however they employ a full circle or arc, or are associated with custom progress bars etc..

are my concerns about wasting resources valid?

is it possible to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```
     Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp).background(Color.White).drawWithContent {
                drawContent()
                // Foreground Arc
                drawArc(
                    color = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#4DB6AC")),
                    225f,
                    260f,
                    false,
                    topLeft = Offset(-40f,50f),
                    size = Size(80f,size.height - 100f)
                )
            }) {
             // your code
    }
```

Customize as per your requirement